# PyTest: how to make tests most likely to fail run first?

Tags: python, pytest

Among thousands of test cases in a project I'm working on there are (about 10) tests which are very likely to fail (because they test something that can be broken easily). In order to make tests fail quickly I'd like to make them run first.

I know `--failed-first` and the [ordering-plugin](https://pytest-ordering.readthedocs.io/en/develop/) - both are helpful but don't fully meet my requirements: I'd like pytest to be aware of all the tests that failed in the past - not only in the last run and it would be great to let pytest discover those cases (rather than having to specify them manually.

So is there an approach do accomplish `--failed-most-often-in-the-past`?

How do you do this?

**Current approach**

By - manually - collecting failing tests you can run them first by just putting them in front of the ones you want to run:

```
time pytest -x tests/some/generic/test_file.py::failing_test tests
```

is much faster than

```
time (pytest -x tests/some/generic/test_file.py::failing_test; pytest -x tests)
```

You could now automatically collect failing tests and prepend them to a file:

```
pytest -x $(cat failing_tests.txt) tests
```

Comment: You can use pytest-sorter https://pypi.org/project/pytest-sorter/ plugin. It runs your test from most likely to fail to the lest likely to fail. It also writes test history in .test_history file for you to inspect. You can easily write custom hooks on top of it to suit your exact needs.